# How to obtain data in javaScript before submitting form in JTable

Tags: javascript, jsp, model-view-controller

Want to get data from JTable form but when I'm trying to get the data it says undefined.

This is **customStudent.js**

```
.......
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#StudentTableContainer').jtable({
        title: 'Student List',
        paging: true,
        pageSize: 10,
        sorting: true, //Enable sorting
        defaultSorting: 'name ASC',
        actions: {
            listAction: actionRoom,
            deleteAction: 'HallManagementServlet?action=DeleteStudent',

              updateAction: 'HallManagementServlet?action=UpdateStudent',


        },
        fields: {
            reg_id: {
                title: 'Registration',
                key: true,
                sort: true,
                create: true,
                edit: false
            },
            name: {
                title: 'Name',
                width: '20%',
                edit: true
            },
            dept_id: {
                title: 'Department',
                edit: true,
                options: 'HallManagementServlet?action=dropDownDepartment',
                width: '5%'
            },
            session: {
                title: 'session',
                edit: true,
                width: '7%'
            },
            degree_type: {
                title: 'Degree type',
                width: '10%',
                options: {'Bachelors/Honours': 'Bachelors/Honours', 'Masters': 'Masters'},
                edit: true,
                list: true
            },
            room_number: {
                title: 'Room',
                width: '5%',
                edit: true,
                options: 'HallManagementServlet?action=dropDownRooms'
            },
            date_of_birth: {
                title: 'Date of Birth',
                type: 'date',
                displayformat: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                edit: true,
                list: false
            },
            blood_group: {
                title: 'Blood Group',
                width: '10%',
                options: {'O-': 'O-', 'O+': 'O+', 'A-': 'A-', 'A+': 'A+', 'B-': 'B-', 'B+': 'B+', 'AB-': 'AB-', 'AB+': 'AB+'},
                edit: true,
                list: false
            },
            contact_number: {
                title: 'Phone',
                width: '10%',
                edit: true,
                list: true
            },
            address_line_1: {
                title: 'Address line 1',
                width: '13%',
                edit: true,
                list: false
            },
            address_line_2: {
                title: 'Address line 6',
                width: '13%',
                edit: true,
                list: false
            },
            fathers_name: {
                title: 'Father\'s Name',
                width: '13%',
                edit: true,
                list: false
            },
            mothers_name: {
                title: 'Mother\'s Name',
                width: '13%',
                edit: true,
                list: false
            },
            email: {
                title: 'E-mail address',
                width: '5%',
                edit: true,
                list: false
            },
            hall_id: {
                title: 'Hall',
                create: false,
                edit: false,
                list: false
            },
            admitted_on: {
                title: 'Admitted On',
                type: 'date',
                displayformat: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                create: true,
                edit: true,
                list: true
            },
            payment_expires_on: {
                title: 'Payment expires on',
                width: '11%',
                type: 'date',
                displayformat: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                create: false,
                edit: true,
                list: true
            },
            paymentStatus: {
                title: 'Payment Status',
                width: '8%',
                options: {'Paid': 'Paid', 'Due': 'Due'},
                create: false,
                edit: false,
                list: true
            },
            imageFile: {
                title: "Image Upload",
                list: false,
                create: true,
                edit: false,
                input: function(data) {
                    return '<input id="docBytes" type="file" name="docBytes" accept="image/*"><iframe name="postiframe" id="postiframe" style="display: none" />';
                }
            }
        },
        formCreated: function(event, data) {
            data.form.find('input[name="reg_id"]').addClass('validate[required,[custom[number]],minSize[10],maxSize[10]');
            data.form.find('input[name="name"]').addClass('validate[required,[custom[onlyLetterSp]]');
            data.form.find('input[name="mothers_name"]').addClass('validate[[custom[onlyLetterSp]]');
            data.form.find('input[name="fathers_name"]').addClass('validate[[custom[onlyLetterSp]]');
            data.form.find('input[name="email"]').addClass('validate[custom[email]]');
            data.form.validationEngine();
        },
        //Validate form when it is being submitted
        formSubmitting: function(event, data) {
            return data.form.validationEngine('validate');
        },
        //Dispose validation logic when form is closed
        formClosed: function(event, data) {
            data.form.validationEngine('hide');
            data.form.validationEngine('detach');
        },
        recordsLoaded: function(event, data) {
            $('.jtable-data-row').click(function() {
                var reg_id = $(this).attr('data-record-key');
                window.location.assign("viewstudent.jsp?reg_id=" + reg_id);
            });
        }

    });
    //Re-load records when user click 'load records' button.
    $('#LoadRecordsButton').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#StudentTableContainer').jtable('load', {
            name: $('#name').val(),
            reg_id: $('#registration').val(),
            dept_id: $('#pd_dept').val(),
            session: $('#pd_session').val(),
            degree_type: $('#pd_degree_type').val()
        });
    });
    //Load all records when page is first shown
    $('#LoadRecordsButton').click();
});
```

More precisely to speak, I want to get the updated date from here:

```
payment_expires_on: {
                    title: 'Payment expires on',
                    width: '11%',
                    type: 'date',
                    displayformat: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                    create: false,
                    edit: true,
                    list: true
                },
```

What should I do to get the date? After getting the date i want to claculate something and show paymentStatus on Jtable.

Comment: Please show us your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
updateAction: function(postData) {
                var payment_date = [];
                console.log("updating from custom function...");
                return $.Deferred(function($dfd) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'HallManagementServlet?action=UpdateStudent',
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: postData,
                        success: function(data) {
                            $.each(data, function(entryindex, entry) {
                              payment_date.push(entry['payment_expires_on']);  
                            });
                            alert(payment_date);
                            $dfd.resolve(data);
                        },
                        error: function() {
                            $dfd.reject();
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
```

Use this custom updateAction. It worked for me.